# How to save a variable based on the a different variable?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to mark exam "is_complete" if the "result" reaches 2. I would like to do this when the form is submitted by the user after completing the test and calculating the results. Both variables are in the same table. Is this possible through PHP or do I need to use Java script.

Here is how I've tried to work out the code.

On the model

```
public function answers()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\ExamResultsAnswers');
}

public function passed()
{

    $instance = new ExamResult;
    $instance->result < 2;

    $var = ExamResult::where('result', '>=', 2)->get();
    $var_is_greater_than_two = ($var >= 2 ? true : false);

    $condition = new ExamResult;
    $condition->is_complete ='1';

    if ($this->compare($instance, $condition)) {
        return $instance->$column == 1;
    }
}
```

On the controller

```
public function exam($course_id, Request $request)
{
    $course = Course::where('id', $course_id)->firstOrFail();
    $answers = [];
    $exam_score = 0;
    foreach ($request->get('question') as $question_id => $answer_id) {
        $question = ExamQuestion::find($question_id);
        $correct_answer = ExamOption::where('exam_question_id', $question_id)
            ->where('id', $answer_id)
            ->where('is_correct', 1)->count() > 0;
        $answers[] = [

            'exam_question_id' => $question_id,
            'exam_option_id' => $answer_id,
            'corect' => $correct_answer
        ];
        if ($correct_answer) {
            $exam_score += $question->score;
        }
    }

    $exam_result = ExamResult::create([
        'exam_id' => $course->exam->id,
        'employee_id' => \Auth::id(),
        'result' => $exam_score,

    ]);


    $exam_result->answers()->createMany($answers);
    $exam_result->passed();
    return redirect()->route('learn.show', [$course, $request])->with('message', 'Test score: ' . $exam_score);
}
```

The controller is supposed to do the following

1. Find all the course and the exam that are associated with the course- this works
2. Then find all the questions and the options for the questions - this works
3. Then if the user selects the correct answer
   then count all correct answers - this works
4. Then I want to save the
   results and mark it complete if the answers are above a 2 correct
   answers. - Here the code saves the exam_id, employee_id and result,
   but it doesn't make it complete if the result is equal to 2. That is
   why I was trying to do this on the model.

Comment: The code which you shared has many bugs.

Comment: Exactly what you want to do and what error are you getting?

Comment: Thanks for responding. The error I'm getting is Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection could not be converted to int

Comment: Yes, as i said there are too many errors in your code and this $var >= 2 might b the reason of the error

Comment: If you explain me a little more what you exactly want to do, then i can modify or guide you to correct your code

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll update the explanation in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code to mark the Exam as completed:

```
$exam_result = ExamResult::create([
    'exam_id' => $course->exam->id,
    'employee_id' => \Auth::id(),
    'result' => $exam_score,
]);
$exam_result->answers()->createMany($answers);

if($exam_result->result > 2) {
    $exam_result->is_complete = 1;
    $exam_result->save();
}
```

Let me know if i misunderstood the requirement.

Another optimised solution

```
$exam_result = ExamResult::create([
    'exam_id' => $course->exam->id,
    'employee_id' => \Auth::id(),
    'result' => $exam_score,
    'is_complete' => $exam_score > 2
]);
$exam_result->answers()->createMany($answers);
```

Comment: Still your code lags the optimization. There can be very less number of queries

Comment: I am adding another code block to my answer, a more optimized than the above, it that one works for you, then use that code

Comment: Thank you very much. The first code helped me understand the logic, the second help me understand the DRY. Fantastic answer.